# Cannot Solve Balancing Parenthesis Using Stack

Tags: python, stack, python-3.5

I am trying to implement a balancing parenthesis operation using stack wherein the program checks what is the input symbol and if it is of the opening Kind((,{,[) it pushes it into the stack and if the symbol is of the closing kind so it checks the last inserted element and if they are the same proceeds with the deletion mechanism. Here is the Code for the same.

```
class Stack(object):
def __init__(self,limit=10):
    self.limit=limit
    self.stack=limit*[]

def isEmpty(self):
    if(len(self.stack))<=0:
        print("Stack is Empty")

def peek(self):
    if len(self.stack)<=0:
        print("Stack is Empty")
    else:
        return(self.stack[-1])

def Delete(self):

    if(len(self.stack)<=0):
        print("Stack is empty.Cannot Delete it More")
    else:
        deleted_var=self.stack.pop()
        #print('Deleted element is:',deleted_var)

def Insertion(self,item):
    if(len(self.stack)>self.limit):
        self.resize()
        self.stack.append(item)
    else:
        inserted_var=self.stack.append(item)
        #print("Element inserted is:",item)

def Size(self):
    print(len(self.stack))

def Display(self):
    print(self.stack[0:self.limit])

def resize(self):
    old_stack=list(self.stack)
    self.limit=2*self.limit
    self.stack=old_stack


user_input=list(input())

BStack=Stack(len(user_input))

character=0


for character in range(len(user_input)):

Inserted_element=None
Deleted_elem=None

if user_input[character]=='(' or user_input[character]=='{' or user_input[character]=='[':
    BStack.Insertion(user_input[character])
    Inserted_element=user_input[character]
    print(Inserted_element)


elif (user_input [character] ==')' or user_input[character]=='}' or user_input[character]==']') and BStack.isEmpty()!=True:
    Deleted_elem=BStack.peek()
    BStack.Delete()
    print(Deleted_elem)


if BStack.Size()>2:
    if Inserted_element!=Deleted_elem:
        print("Symbos are not same")

if BStack.isEmpty():
    print("Symbols Match")
else:
    print("No Match")
```

And I'm also learning the Data structures from this book-Data Structure and Algorithmic Thinking with Python by  Narasimha karumanchi. If anyone has read it, i would like to hear your opinion and if anyone has a better book,Please let me know.

Comment: Did you get any errors? What have you done to try solve your problem? In future, these would be good things to include in your question :).

Comment: Small side note: don't worry about resizing arrays in Python. *This happens automatically behind the scenes*. In fact, the statement `limit*[]` just gives an empty array `[]` anyway. I assume you got the idea from your book.

Comment: I believe that the code is somewhere wrong and it would not work for some test cases.For some of the cases the code does work.So i just needed someone to tell me how do i correct this.

Comment: Show an example of your failing test cases and the expected output.  Are we to guess what the problem is?  Also your code is not indented correctly.  We should be able to copy-paste to try it out.